# Tensorflow tfds.load "generating train examples" loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, tensorflow-datasets

[Details about the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlAES.jpg)
I used the tdfs.load to import the 'kddcup' dataset from tensorflow_dataset, but when I ran the code the execution of the code got stuck in the 'Generating train examples...' part.

I also tried to reduce the size of the dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

#train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('kddcup99', split=['train[:10]', 'test[:10]'])
"""
(ds_train, ds_test) = tfds.load(
    'kddcup99',
    split=['train[:1%]', 'test[:1%]']
)
"""
#ds_train = tfds.load('kddcup99', split=['train[0:10]'])
ds_test = tfds.load('kddcup99', split=['test[0:10]'], as_supervised=None)
#assert isinstance(ds_train, tf.data.Dataset)
assert isinstance(ds_test, tf.data.Dataset)
#print(ds_train)
print(ds_test)
```

Someone has got the same issue? Could be a problem with the installation of tensorflow_datasets?
Thanks for all the answers.